# Updating a number in a TextView every second

Tags: java, android, scope, handlers

I'm writing my first app in which I need to update the number in a text view every second until a button is pressed. Using a handler seems to be impossible because the number is created and stored outside of the handler, but it can't be declared final because it needs to change. `Thread.sleep`also seems to make the app hang indefinitely, before some code is executed that is written above it.

```
final TextView countView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        countView.setText("100,000,000,000");

    //set a Calendar object to be 00:00:00:00 on Jan 1, 2015
    final Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.set(2015, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

final Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //set a Calendar to be the time that the button is clicked and find the difference in ms between it and startTime
                Calendar nowTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                double milStart = startTime.getTimeInMillis();
                double milNow = nowTime.getTimeInMillis();
                double diff = (milNow-milStart)/1000;     //difference in seconds between "start" date and current date

                double total = 100000000000L;   //# that needs to be updated
                for(long i = 0L; i < diff; i++) {
                    total += 1.8;
                }
                countView.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(total));
```

I need to continue to increment `total` by 1.8 every second or by 1 every 556 milliseconds.

```
while(true) {
   countView.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(total));
   total += 1.8;
   try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
 }
```

Causes the app to hang indefinitely as soon as the button is clicked, so that even the first `countView.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(total));` doesn't execute.

Using a handler doesn't seem possible to me since `total` can't work if declared final, but creating a variable inside the handler and looping it would cause the value to never change.

Am I missing an obvious solution? This is my first real endeavor with Java so it's all new to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you may use Handler

```
Handler h = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            count++;
            textView.setText(""+count*1.8);
            h.postDelayed(this, 1000); //ms
        }
    };
h.postDelayed(r, 1000); // one second in ms
```

for stopping you may use [h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: This works, but doesn't tackle the problem I have. I have a number that is determined earlier in the code, and need to update _that_ number but can't drag it into the runnable because it isn't final. It can't be declared final because it needs to change

Comment: define this number in your Activity "globally", recover/recreate/obtain from anywhere in `onCreate` method or wherever. after that put above code and then you will be able to ++ this int inside `Runnable`